# Communication between Windows Phone 8 and ASP.NET MVC Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-phone-8, azure-blob-storage

I' m using Web API to retrieve SAS for uploading picture to Windows Azure blob storage. Unfortunately it doesn't work. The funny thing is that it work in any other application, even in Windows Store app. This is my controller code:

```
// GET api/users?container="test"&blobname="test.jpg"
    public string Get(string container, string blobname)
    {
        try
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ConnectionString"));
            //CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient(); ;
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(container);
            blobContainer.CreateIfNotExist();

            BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
            containerPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;

            // Define a 4 hour window that the Windows 8 client can write to Azure Blob Storage.
            containerPermissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add("mypolicy", new SharedAccessPolicy()
            {
                Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Write, // | SharedAccessPermissions.Read ,
                //To be available immediately don't set SharedAccessStartTime =
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(4))
            });

            // Set the permissions so that Windows 8 client can write to the container
            // for the 4 hours specified above.
            blobContainer.SetPermissions(containerPermissions);

            // Create the shared access signature that will be added to the URL.
            string sas = blobContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessPolicy(), "mypolicy");

            // Creat the URI to be return to the Windows 8 client that will be used to write
            // to blob storage.
            return string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", blobContainer.Uri, blobname, sas);

        }
        catch
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

and here is the client:

```
string photoSasUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:81/api/users?container={0}&blobname={1}";
                    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format(photoSasUrl, "profiles-pictures", "test.jpg")))
                    {
                        // Retrieve Shared Access Signature from Web Service
                        var sasUrl = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        // Trim any miscellaneous quotes
                        sasUrl = sasUrl.Trim('"');

                        // Load bytes of image into content object
                        var content = new StreamContent(e.ChosenPhoto);
                        // Content-Type will be image/jpeg
                        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpg");
                        // Write the bytes of the photo to blob storage
                        using (var uploadResponse = await client.PutAsync(new Uri(sasUrl), content))
                        {
                            if (uploadResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                // If successful, show on screen
                                MessageBox.Show("Upload Successful");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
                    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:81/api/values"));
                }
                catch { }
```

What I found is that it doesn't work for sample values controller which is generated by default on web API project creation either.

Comment: I see a 'api/users' and 'api/values'..possibly 2 controllers?..could you elaborate as to which/what is not working exactly?

Comment: Neither one works when it called from WP. Both work when called from any other platform.

Comment: you mean you are unable to hit the controllers? are you seeing 404 errors?...like i am not clear as to what is not working here...

Comment: Yes I'm getting 404 Not Found response message every time on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the address `http://127.0.0.1:81/api/`. `127.0.0.1` points to your Windows Phone device, not your local server. Use the IP address of your machine instead.

Comment: I'm using windows azure local emulator. It's the address where web API site is hosted. How should I change that address?

Comment: @RadeMilovic Not localhost, the IP address of your computer on your local network. You can get it by typing the command `ipconfig` in the console

Comment: I get this:
PPP adapter BENETON:
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.250.82
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Intern
al Switch):
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.80.80
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Virtual Switch):
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.250.250.80
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Comment: I think those two do not share the same ip address.

Comment: @RadeMilovic Not sure which IP address is the right one, but I'd go with `169.254.80.80`. But basically, the problem is that the Windows Phone application is running in an emulator. It's almost the same as if the application was running on a separate device. `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` (both are equivalent) mean "the device the application is running on". It cannot work with your Windows Phone app because it's running on a separate virtual device (while the other apps you've tried, like the Windows Store app, are running directly on your computer).

Comment: That was my assumption from the start, but I'm not a experienced developer and I needed confirmation. That is very stupid, how anyone from Microsoft expect that people develop apps which use azure which can't be tested locally. Thank you for your time. I really appreciate it. I will upload web api site to the cloud and the try to create windows phone client.

Comment: @RadeMilovic In theory, the computer and the emulator are on the same virtual network, so it should be possible to communicate using the right IP address. Have you tried the one I pointed out?

Comment: No I haven't. How can I change the address of the phone emulator or windows azure emulator?

Comment: The IP address `169.254.80.80` **should** be your computer's address when accessed from the emulator. Therefore, all you have to do is changing the link of your service: `http://169.254.80.80:81/api/users?container={0}&blobname={1}`